# How to change image link onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to change the image of a link on click.

```
<div class="mobilestoreimg">
    <a href="/store-locator"><img src="../includes/mobile-location.png"/></a>
</div>
```

so when you click the link it changes the image from

```
mobile-location.png
```

too

```
mobile-location-blk.png
```

any ideas?

Comment: Load jQuery, load jQuery UI, load angularjs, load requirejs (just to be sure). Then write `document.querySelector('mobilestoreimg').addEventListener('click, function() { this.querySelector('img').src = 'mobile-location-blk.png'; }, false);`

Comment: Then remove jQuery, remove jQuery UI, remove angularjs and remove requirejs as well. Then it would be an idea to serch for `addEventListener javascript` on google

Comment: A click on a link will forward you to a new location. Why would you want to change the image of that link?

Comment: to show that you have clicked the link and the page is loading

Answer (score 1):

try this one. it will really help you.

if you are using jQuery.

```
 $(function() {    
    $('.mobilestoreimg>a').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('img').attr('src',"newValue");
    })
  })
```

otherwise

```
document.querySelector('.mobilestoreimg>a').addEventListener('click, function() {   this.querySelector('img').src = 'newValue'; }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ID to a `<img>` element and then bind `onClick` event to change the src.

```
<div class="mobilestoreimg">
    <a href="/store-locator"><img id="imgChange" src="../includes/mobile-location.png"/></a>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$('#imgChange').on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('src','../includes/mobile-location-blk.png'); 
});
```

Comment: that didnt work image stays the same once you click it

Comment: I really don't understand why people insist on using jquery for something as simple as this.  That's a lot of overhead for something that could be accomlished safely and easily without it.

Comment: @M0n5terBunny That does exactly what you asked. If you wanted the `src` to toggle you need to ask that.

Comment: do you have a suggestion

Comment: well toggle so you click the link it changes the image to show youve clicked the image and loads the page

Answer (score 0):

Alternative version using jQuery:

```
  $(function() {    
    $('a').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('img').attr('src',"newValue");
    })
  })
```

I did a jsfiddle, but the site does not like interrupting events, anyway, if you want it it's here but without a link on the href: http://jsfiddle.net/g1z4zqt9/2/